# Microsoft ML can't use opset 11 despite nuget package installed

Tags: ml.net, windows-machine-learning

I'm trying to build a simple object detection runner, really just following this MS Docs guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/tutorials/tensorflow-deploy-model

I already figured out building the View and adding capabilities so the provided code actually compiles.
Just one more problem right now: When creating the session, it crashes claiming "Unknown model file format version" which seems to translate to "Opset of the model you use is not supported".
Looking at github issues google showed me, I'm supposed to install the Microsoft.AI.MachineLearning nuget package and all is well. Except when I installed it, nothing changed.

So, what's left to do beside open yet another github issue? I already re-exported my model from opset 15 to opset 11 because the nuget package only supports that.

I'm on windows 10, UWP targeting 2004.